# Merge two tables while dragging one column from one table to the other

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

With `Sql Server 2014`:

I have two tables - Events and Locations, that share a time column and I need to merge them into one table order by time. In the Events table there is an Event column that I need to place in all the Locations row following that event (time wise), here is an example:

Events:

```
time   event  
------------  
09:00   2  
09:10   3  
10:15   1  
10:17   2  
10:30   3
```

Locations:

```
time    X   Y
-------------
09:01   1   3
09:02   2   3
09:05   4   1
09:09   6   4
09:10   7   8
09:11   8   8
09:12   9   7
10:17   1   2
10:19   5   4
10:20   4   3
10:25   5   4
10:28   3   5
```

Merged Table:

```
time    X   Y  event
--------------------
09:00   0   0  2
09:01   1   3  2   <
09:02   2   3  2   <
09:05   4   1  2   <
09:09   6   4  2   <
09:10   0   0  3
09:10   7   8  3   <
09:11   8   8  3   <
09:12   9   7  3   <
10:15   0   0  1
10:17   0   0  2
10:17   1   2  2   <
10:19   5   4  2   <
10:20   4   3  2   <
10:25   5   4  2   <
10:28   3   5  2   <
10:30   0   0  3
```

The elements that mark with '<' are the inserted Events.

Any ideas and help on how to perform this task is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UNION ALL` and `APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/165da/1/0)

```
SELECT 
    [Time], X = 0, Y = 0, [Event]
FROM [Events]

UNION ALL

SELECT l.*, x.Event
FROM Locations l
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM [Events]
    WHERE [Time] <= l.[Time]
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
)x
ORDER BY [Time]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and clean response! I adopt it!